# VirtoCommerce Product Persistently Not for Sale

Tags: virtocommerce

It seems nothing I do will enable purchasing a product.

If you go to http://forestum-webshop.azurewebsites.net/fi-fi/forestum/pihakoristeet/puulinnut and hover over the product, it says `Not for Sale`

What would be the most common causes for product being `Not for Sale`?

Comment: There might be different reasons for this, one being pricing is not set another product is marked not for sale. Or inventory checking is set but no inventory quantity specified. Also try checking 2.0 version, as there are many more improvements to that version.